# call instance method with class instance variable - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to call an instance method (defined in model) from the instance variable in controller but could not get that work and server logs saying

> undefined method `active_users' for #< Admin

**controller**

```
@admin = Admin.first
@admin.active_users
```

**Admin Model**

```
def self.active_users
  byebug
end
```

I know that we can call it through the class directly like `Admin.active_users` .

Why is it not accessible by instance of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`active_users` method is defined for `Admin` object, not for its instances.

I do not know what you are trying to do, but message receiver matters.

To make `@admin.active_users` work, define a method an instance method:

```
def active_users
  byebug
end
```

The thing is, that `active_users` (both with and without `self`) are instance methods. It is just that objects for which these methods defined are different.

The method with `self` is a "class instance method", while the one without `self` is an "instance method", e.g. method accessible by instances of the class `Admin`.

Comment: i simply want to call an instance method directly from instance variable . can you guide me to some cool way in rails

Comment: i checked that too . but did not worked . but i try it again

Comment: @ImranNaqvi: the problem is that `active_users` is a method on completely separate instance, `Admin` of type `Class`, not `@admin` of type `Admin`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no actually moving to class method worked . dont know why it didn't worked on first attempt . thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you write `def self.something_method`, method will be available only for class, as in your example. If you want create method for `object`, you have to create method without `self`, like this: `def something_method`.
For example:

```
class Admin
  def self.class_method
    p 'class method'
  end

  def something_method
    p 'method for object' 
  end
end

@admin = Admin.create(something_params)
 # You can also use 'Admin.new', but it will not save your admin in database, or 'Admin.first', like in your example.
@admin.something_method
#=> 'method for object'
@admin.class_method
#=> not working :( 

Admin.something_method
#=> not working :( 
Admin.class_method
#=> 'class method'
```